# Logstash Config how to trasfer aws s3 csv without header to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I have sample csv file in s3 with 3 column **without any header**. But during data transfer from s3 csv to elasticsearch, I want to give some name to each column (in my case id, name, age to column 0 to 2 respectively).

**Input Sample.csv**

```
  1,myname,23
  2,myname2,24
```

**Expected Output should be following doc in ES index:**

```
        [{
            "_index": "user_detail",
            "_type": "user_detail_type",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "myname",
                "age": "23"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "user_detail",
            "_type": "user_detail_type",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "myname2",
                "age": "24"
            }
        }]
```

**Logstash config that I have written is:**

```
input {
      s3 {
         bucket => "users"
         region => "us-east-1"
         watch_for_new_files => false
         prefix => "user.csv"
        }
}

filter {
  // Need help here
}

output {
     elasticsearch {
          hosts => "localhost:9200"
          index => "user_detail"
          document_type => "user_detail_type"
          document_id => "%{id}"
     }
}
```

**Doubt:**
What should I write in filter section or any change in config to convert column[0] => id, column[1] => name, column[2] => age during Elasticsearch insertion.

Comment: use the csv codec on your input. You can set column names with the `columns` option

Comment: My question is for the case when I dont have header in csv, Could you please explain a bit more it. @baudsp

Comment: parsing csv without headers is a supported use case of the csv codec, as you can hard-code the headers in the configuration of the codec

Comment: @baudsp Thanks it worked with csv filter with columns. I was using it in wrong way before. I added filter section with following config.
filter {
  csv {
    columns => ["id", "name", "age"]
    separator => ","
  }
}